# Running against compiled ruby

Tags: ruby

I want to contribute to the ruby-core and I have checked out the source, built it and now I want to run a test from test folder against my built version of ruby.

I'm having trouble, I've included the local paths which ruby looks in for libraries but it can't find thread...

```
./ruby -I./lib -I. -I.ext/common test/socket/test_socket.rb
```

I just get:

```
~/ruby/lib/rubygems.rb:9:in `require': cannot load such file -- thread (LoadError)
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It would appear that you are not referencing the directories properly.

Let's assume you have cloned [the Ruby GitHub repo](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/) into `~/ruby` and that you have run `./configure --prefix=~/ruby-2.5.1`, followed by `make` and `make install`, so that your Ruby binary is the file `~/ruby-2.5.1/bin/ruby`.

If your shell is currently in the directory `~/ruby-2.5.1/bin`, then the correct command to enter is:

```
./ruby -I~/ruby/lib -I~/ruby -I~/ruby/ext/common ~/ruby/test/socket/test_socket.rb
```

Note that since your working directory is `~/ruby-2.5.1/bin` that you cannot reference the Ruby source code in `~/ruby` by using `./`. `./` means [the relative path to the current directory](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/397526/218427).

The output should now be:

```
Loaded suite ~/ruby/test/socket/test_socket
Started
....................................
Finished in 10.26308 seconds.
36 tests, 115 assertions, 0 failures, 0 errors, 0 pendings, 0 omissions, 0 notifications
100% passed
```

The version of Ruby you were probably using at the time was Ruby 2.2 (released December 25th 2014), but the same answer applies to that version because the directory structure has not changed between then and 2.5, both for the source code and for the compiled and installed binary versions.